# Merge 2 Id fields in query to use ampscript to update a salesforce object

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, sql

[image]I would like to update a custom salesforce object when a marketing cloud email is sent.  I have a transaction object and once the email is sent, I would like to update the description field to “Acknowledged”.

To use ampscript code UpdateSingleSalesforceObject I need the transaction Id in my data extension however I already have the contact ID (for email sending) in my data extension so I’m stuck on how to pull in a second ID in the query.

Is there a way to rename the transaction Id before pulling it into my data extensions?

I was also wondering do I need to create 2 separate data extensions in Contact builder?  I have never used Contact builder so I’m not sure how I would link the data extensions together.

Will this even work putting the below code at the beginning of an email?
%%[
var @result
set @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(‘AQB__Transaction__c’,’TransId’,’AQB__Description__c’,’Acknowledged’)
]%%

Appreciate any guidance, I'm getting above my skill set but I really want this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a lookup between these two objects Contacts and Transaction. You can create the sendable data extension using query activity and pull the transaction ids along with the contact ids in a separate column. Once you have the transaction ids in your sendable data extension, you can perform the above UpdateSingleSalesforceObject in your email.

Comment: thank you so much for your assistance.  I do have a lookup and when i try to pull the transaction Id in, it tells me I have already pulled in an Id column.  I have a screenshot of the error and will try to figure out where to upload it so you can see it.

Comment: code works fine until I add line #4.

Comment: Thank you so much you got me pushed in the right direction.  I found that i could rename the ID field by using AS after it.  This worked.
Select ATransCont.AQB__Amount__c, 
ATransCont.AQB__Date__c, 
ATransCont.Designation_Name__c,
ATransCont.Id as TransId,
AContacts.FirstName, 
AContacts.Email,
AContacts.Id,
Accounts.DRM_Email__c
From ATransCont
Inner Join AContacts on ATransCont.AQB__Account__c=AContacts.AccountId
Inner Join Accounts on AContacts.AccountId = Accounts.Id